# Django query fast while rendering slow

Tags: mysql, django, optimization

I'm running a website with Django and MySQL and I'm trying to optimize it.
For that purpose I use the django debug toolbar and I pay a particular attention to the SQL part which is, I think, the reason why the load of my page is long.

When I look at the SQL part in django debug toolbar, it says that my queries take around 90ms in total.
But if I put a timer around the rendering function in python, then it takes more than 3s (which is closer to what I actually see when reloading the page)...

How comes the query is that fast compared to the rendering?

EDIT: here is the code in the template simplified to its maximum:

```
<div id="content_annonces" class="ui-widget ui-corner-all">
     <table>
         {% if latest_annonces_list %}
             here goes the content
         {% else %}
             nothing found
         {% endif %}
     </table>
</div>
```

as you can see, the only peace of code that is supposed to be costly is the SQL query requested when calling the object latest_annonces_list.
But when I profile it with django debug toolbar it says this query has an elapsed of 90ms while the rendering takes around 3s ...

And here goes the content of latest_annonces_list:

```
result = Annonce.objects.select_related('vehicule', 'vehicule__marque')
         .filter(vehicule__marque__in=self.marques).order_by('prix')[:10]
```

Models here:

```
class Marque(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, primary_key=True, max_length=100)

class Vehicule(models.Model):
    modele     = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, max_length=100)
    gen_modele = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
    marque     = models.ForeignKey(Marque)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categorie)
    click      = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class Annonce(models.Model):
    vehicule      = models.ForeignKey(Vehicule, db_index=True)
    porte         = models.ForeignKey(Porte, db_index=True)
    carburant     = models.ForeignKey(Carburant, db_index=True)
    bv            = models.ForeignKey(Boite, db_index=True)
    prix          = models.DecimalField(db_index=True,max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    km            = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    dpt           = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50)
    annonceur     = models.ForeignKey(Annonceur, db_index=True)
    img           = models.URLField()
    url           = models.URLField(max_length=2000)
    finition      = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    cylindree     = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    moteur        = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    annee         = models.DateTimeField(u'annee vehicule', db_index=True)
    pub_date      = models.DateTimeField(u'date publication')
    last_touched  = models.DateTimeField(u'derniere modification')
    last_scan     = models.DateTimeField(u'dernier scan')
    type_ann      = models.ForeignKey(Type_Annonce, db_index=True)
    type_vendeur  = models.ForeignKey(Vendeu
```

r, db_index=True)

Comment: Captain Obvious here - maybe you have inefficient code in your rendering logic?

Comment: well I thought of it but the only thing that can be inefficient in the template is query related... The rest is just composed of strings basically...

Comment: Ok, I was just joking. The thing is that we can't say anything  about the problem without seeing the code. Can you provide a small example of your problem?

Comment: Can you also add some code where you create that content ("here goes the content" part)?

Comment: here you go. And thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

90ms is still pretty much for a query executed against a local database, so I guess there are many joins.

General rule in such a situation is to reduce the ORM usage by:

- selecting only required field or deferring the unneeded and costly
  lookups - see
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer and
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only
- if you are only displaying the exact value of fields, use `values()` or `values_list()` on your queryset, which will prevent Django ORM from building all the objects and executing relevant signals

Probably the quickest way to have a significant gain is either to cache the QuerySets using johnny-cache http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/ or cache the output using `{% cache ... %}`

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I did. I tried 2 things: use a nonrel database (mongodB) but it was too much work to migrate. Second thing was to get rid of ORM usage (it was too much). I'll try to play with values and values_list though. It seems interesting in my case. However I still don't get why I had such a difference between the query execution and the rendering elapsed time. Oh and about the cache, I already use it but I wanted to improve performance on the side.