# Django admin - building HTML page with 2,000 inlines is slow, while DB query is fast

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

**Question in short**: I have a model admin with tabular inlines. There are around 2,000 related records. Fetching them from the database takes only 1 ms, but then it takes 4-5 seconds to render them into an HTML page. What can I do to speed this up?

**Question in detail:**

I have the following (simplified) models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

class Measurement(models.Model):
    decimal_settings = {'decimal_places': 1, 'max_digits': 8, 'null': True, 'blank': True, 'default': None}

    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='measurements', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day = models.DateField()  # DB indexing is done using the unique_together with location

    temperature_avg = models.DecimalField(**decimal_settings)
    temperature_min = models.DecimalField(**decimal_settings)
    temperature_max = models.DecimalField(**decimal_settings)

    feels_like_temperature_avg = models.DecimalField(**decimal_settings)
    feels_like_temperature_min = models.DecimalField(**decimal_settings)
    feels_like_temperature_max = models.DecimalField(**decimal_settings)

    wind_speed = models.DecimalField(**decimal_settings)
    precipitation = models.DecimalField(**decimal_settings)
    precipitation_duration = models.DecimalField(**decimal_settings)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('day', 'location')
```

I have created the following inlines on the Location admin:

```
class MeasurementInline(TabularInline):
    model = Measurement
    fields = ('day',
              'temperature_avg', 'temperature_min', 'temperature_max',
              'feels_like_temperature_avg', 'feels_like_temperature_min', 'feels_like_temperature_max',
              'wind_speed', 'precipitation', 'precipitation_duration')
    readonly_fields = fields
    extra = 0
    show_change_link = False

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

When I open a Location in the admin panel, I get a nice-looking overview of all measurements.

[image: Location admin panel]

This takes however 4-5 seconds to load. I have installed Django Debug Toolbar to see what takes so much time. To my surprise, it didn't spend time in the database, but in CPU.

[image: Django Debug Toolbar screenshot]

When clicking for more details on CPU usage, I see the following. I find it hard to interpret. I assume it's taking a long time to build the HTML page from the template.

[image: CPU usage details from Django Debug Toolbar]

Now my questions are:

- How can I easily paginate these inlines, so I don't need to show 2,000 at once? I tried to add `paginate_by = 100` to the class `MeasurementInline`, but I still see all 2,000 records.
- How do I investigate further what takes so much CPU time to return the admin page?
- What can I do to speed this up?

p.s. I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870302/django-query-fast-while-rendering-slow), but there is no answer given there either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in your django Location admin class to add system pagination? I didn't think it's MeasurementInline to define this one. Like that :

```
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('y', 'z', 'year')
    list_per_page = 5 # No of records per page
```

In any case, if your administration site is slow, you are displaying and injecting 2000 inlines on the front-end. So you need to put the pagination in order to reduce the cpu usage by your client (chrome, firefox etc.)

Comment: Unfortunately, that `list_per_page` defines how many locations to show on the Locations list page, but not how many Measurement inlines to show on a Location detail page.